# What is the most appropriate method to get an approximate analytic solution for nonlinear system of ordinary differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a coupled system of non-linear second-order ordinary differential equations that I need to get an approximate analytic solution for, what is the most appropriate method to solve such a system? I need to know the explicit dependence of the solution on some physical parameters in the equations, so I think that a series solution can't help(isn't that true in this case?)
Edit: here is the system that I need to solve: $$x''=\frac{a y'+c}{\sin\theta}$$  $$\theta ''=-ax'\sin\theta-ay'\sin\theta-b\sin\theta+d\cos\theta$$  $$y''=ky'\sin^2\theta+f\sin\theta\cos\theta+h\sin^2\theta$$
where (a,b,c,d,f,h) are all constant parameters, and $x$,$\theta$,$y$ are all unknown functions of time

Comment: @Moo I have already solved the system numerically in matlab, and it wasn't hard to do so, I now need an analytic solution even an approximate one since I know that an exact analytic solution is most likely impossible for this system.

Comment: I can but it may take some time for I am not too fast in writing with mathjax, but I don't think it would be necessary.

Comment: Ok, I am working on it, thanks for your concern.

Comment: @Moo I am done, here is the system.

Comment: Can you describe what the encompassing use case is? A fixed step size integration interpreted as function evaluation might be the closest you may come in terms of approximate "analytical" solution. Often what is wanted is pointwise evaluation of function values and low order derivatives to use in Newton's method or optimization algorithms, which is routinely used in shooting methods for boundary value problems.

Comment: @LutzL I mean in my case I need to know what dependence of x,y and $\theta$ on the constant parameters appearing in the equations.  What are these optimization methods?